# Which Puranas or scriptures contain the sloka purāṇaṃ sarva śāstrāṇāṃ

Tags: puranas

Which Puranas or scriptures contain the śloka

पुराणं सर्व शास्त्राणां प्रथमं ब्रह्मणा स्मृतम् ।

अनन्तरं च वक्त्रेभ्यो वेदास्तस्य विनिर्गताः ॥

purāṇaṃ sarva śāstrāṇāṃ prathamaṃ brahmaṇā smṛtam ।

anantaraṃ ca vaktrebhyo vedāstasya vinirgatāḥ ॥

The meaning is "Among all shastras Puranas are the first to be remembered by Brahmā. Later Vedas came out of his mouth."

Comment: Is this  one shloka? It seems both lines are from matsya puran but the both lines are not part of one whole shlokaपुराणसर्वशास्त्राणां प्रथमं ब्रह्मणा स्मृतम्  ।
नित्यं शब्दमयं पुण्यं शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम्  ॥ ३.३ ॥
अनन्तरं च वक्त्रेभ्यो वेदास्तस्य विनिःसृताः  ।
मीमांसान्यायविद्याश्च प्रमाणाष्टकसंयुताः  ॥ ३.४ ॥
वेदाभ्यासरतस्यास्य प्रजाकामस्य मानसाः  ।

Comment: See this link for shloka https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.sanskritworld.in/public/assets/book/book_50dbe7b1e4245.txt&ved=0ahUKEwjXsMuryZHPAhUGymMKHcDRAD4QFggjMAI&usg=AFQjCNEe48gJPDdSoowvVWQAt4xWiq0f5A&sig2=-HK1f5f_u62kM6GamQrixw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Matsya Purana Chapter 53](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-53/topic-1) says

> **मत्स्य उवाच -**
>
> **पुराणं सर्व शास्त्राणां प्रथमं ब्रह्मणा स्मृतम् ।**
>
> **अनन्तरं च वक्त्रेभ्यो वेदास्तस्य विनिर्गताः ॥  (53.3)**
>
> **Matsya said -**
> **Brahmā remembered in the beginning first the Purāṇās among all**
> **śāstras. Afterwards Brahmā uttered the four vedas out of his mouth.**

[Matsya Purana Chapter 3](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-03/topic-1) says

> **पुराणं सर्व शास्त्राणां प्रथमं ब्रह्मणा स्मृतम् ।**
>
> नित्यं शब्दमयं पुण्यं शतकोटिप्रविस्तरम् ॥ (3.3)
>
> **Before the creation of all the śāstras, Brahmā remembered the Purāṇās**,
> which are ever lasting, full of śabda (meaning veda or essence of
> vedas), auspicious comprised of hundred crores of ślokas.
>
> **अनन्तरं च वक्त्रेभ्यो वेदास्तस्य विनिःसृताः ।**
>
> मीमांसा न्यायविद्याश्च प्रमाणाष्टक संयुताः ॥ (3.4)
>
> **Thereafter vedas emerged out of Brahmā's mouth** along with their angās
> mīmāṁsa and nyāya.

[Brahmanda Purana Chapter 1](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/brahmanda-mahapuranam/vol-i/chapter-01/topic-1) says

> वक्ष्यामि तान्पुरस्तात्तु विस्तरेण यथा क्रमम् ।
>
> **प्रथमं सर्व शास्त्राणां पुराणं ब्रह्मणा स्मृतम् ॥ (1.40)**
>
> (Suta says) I shall narrate them in detail later on and in the proper
> order. **At first among all śāstras the purāṇās were remembered or heard**
> **by Brahmā.**
>
> **अनन्तरं च वक्त्रेभ्यो वेदास्तस्य विनिःसृताः ।**
>
> अंगानि धर्मशास्त्रं च व्रतानि नियमास्तथा ॥  (1.41)
>
> **Then the vedas came out of his mouth**. Similarly the vedāngās,
> Dharmaśāstras, vratā and holy observances also followed them.