# When exactly were the puranas were written?

Tags: puranas, vishnu-purana

Many western scholars agree that Puranas were written during 2nd century and so on.but some scholars give date before 200 BC. Like some scholars agree Vishnu Purana to be written in 3rd century, while some scholars give the date before 300 BC? So when exactly they were written?

Comment: Puranas are actually transmitted orally from generation to generation. They were written much later and you can take their dating techniques to grain of salt as they are never accurate. Puranas say Puranas were first remembered by  Brahma. See [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14941/3500).

Comment: You should ask about when they were known / composed, not when they were written.